# Performance Impact of offscreen elements

Tags: javascript, css

In a single page app I am doing, some pages become cached and transition towards the bottom of screen, off the viewport.

Those pages stay immediately below the viewport and do not have a property like display:none attached, because hiding them requires a bit more work.

Will this be a performance impact to the app, if there are complex elements off the viewport and not set to display:none?

Comment: Web browsers are built so that the impact of offscreen elements is a lot less than onscreen elements, but it very much depends on your use case (what kind of elements are they, how many are there), so this is a pretty broad question.

Comment: I like this question, but maybe you should make it more specific by simply asking something like "does [browser] use resources on offscreen elements?"

Comment: I unserstand. Let's just say there is no JavaScript attached with the cached views, no Dom element searches being run either so the size and JavaScript code do not matter. This is purely about how much impact expensive CSS (think box shadow, etc) and long HTML make on drawing performance. That being said, I really would like to see some experiment being done on how much such elements affect drawing performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe so. Aspecially if you are creating these elements with javascript. You want to decrease the DOM "interaction" as much as possible. Even If you are not creating these in javascript it's pretty obvious that it will take longer to load your page if there is more data to load. Though data that is created outside the viewport do not matter as much as the data that is created inside the viewport; it is still data being created.